# Get multiple subsets of columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

So I have this big DataFrame in Python which looks something like this

```
GEN A0A1    A0B1    A1B0    A1B1    ...
0   1   2   3   4   5
0   1   2   3   4   5
0   1   2   3   4   5
0   1   2   3   4   5
0   1   2   3   4   5
```

The columns AxBy go on for quite a while. How would I select multiple columns of this DataFrame that do not overlap? So for example I get a subset from columns 1-2; 3-4; 5-6 and so on.

I then want to transform these subsets independently from each other (size remains the same) so I would also need a way to either get a reference to these columns or some way to save them back again to the same position I got them. Is there an elegant way in pandas to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with so far. Maybe not the most efficient but maybe it helps someone:

```
seq = bigFrame.columns[<start-index>:]
subCols = [seq[i:i + <grouped-columns-amount>] for i in range(0, len(seq), <grouped-columns-amount>)]
    
    
for cols in subCols:
    print(bigFrame[cols])
```